# Terracotta Web Sessions - dynamically reload configuration and/or change configured webapps on the fly

Tags: session, cluster-computing, terracotta

Is there a way to dynamically reload the Terracotta configuration file without restarting Terracotta and losing Session replication for *every* web app?

---

**More Info:** I'm in charge of about 30 unruly, legacy Java Web Applications.  My goal is to setup our servers so that I can quickly redirect all traffic from one Tomcat instance to another without missing a beat or losing Session data (for upgrade purposes; I do a lot of "emergency response", so after-hours deployment isn't often soon enough).

I've already got a reverse proxy setup, so session replication should round out the requirements.

I struggled with Tomcat 5.5's native Session Replication features for a few days, and never did get it working 100% as advertised.  Terracotta seems to be a good solution, but only if it can be updated dynamically without stopping replication for every app.

Comment: Hi drfloob, did you find the answer to your question?
I'd be interested to know

Comment: No, that soon became someone else's problem (which I'm sure is still not solved). If it's any help to you, though: in the end, I had decided it would be easiest to do without native sessions and use external storage for session data. I lean towards simple, distributed document/key-value stores like mnesia, CouchDB, or memcached. I'd still do that today if I were in a similar situation.